# SQL SUM with Where Condition

Tags: sql, sum, where-clause

```
sum(raceprice) / sum(bidding_price) * sum( bidding_price Where bidding_type = 'small') 
- bet_price as Totla_profit
```

I keep getting error message about that sum condition, don't know what is wrong with it, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
sum(bidding_price Where bidding_type = 'small')
```

with

```
sum(case when bidding_type = 'small' 
         then bidding_price 
         else 0 
    end)
```

Comment: Sorry what does the "else 0" mean, it returns as 0? because it returns as 0 then the answer will be 0.

Comment: This is a conditional sum. It sum the `bidding_price` if `bidding_type = 'small'`. Otherwise it adds `0` to the sum